# Select rows matching to summary using CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate, common-table-expression

Trying to write a T-SQL query for SQL Server, which takes `itemid` and `quantity summary` (always > 0) as parameters, and selecting transactions matching to this summary in desc order by date (including rows with the remainder of the subtraction).

So for example if I want to select item 1 with 10 qty. Scripts selected all the ordered transactions covering this amount, even if in summary it will more than 10. (1 +> +3 > +0 > +10 > stop!)

```
create table #items(itemid int, qtySum money)

insert into #items 
values (1, 10), (2, 33), (3, 15), (4, 3),
       (5, 3), (6, 15), (7, 15)

create table #transactions
(
    itemid int, 
    trid int, 
    trdate date, 
    qty money
)

insert into #transactions 
values (1, 1, '20240212', 1),
       (1, 2, '20240211', 3),
       (1, 3, '20240211', 0),
       (1, 4, '20240210', 10),
       (1, 5, '20240209', 10),
       (1, 6, '20240208', 1),
       (2, 7, '20240212', 22),
       (2, 8, '20240211', 11),
       (2, 9, '20240210', -5),
       (2, 10, '20240210', -4),
       (2, 11, '20240209', 9),
       (2, 12, '20240209', 4),
       (2, 13, '20240209', 6),
       (3, 15, '20240212', 10),
       (3, 16, '20240211', -2),
       (3, 17, '20240210', -3),
       (3, 18, '20240209', 8),
       (3, 19, '20240208', 4),
       (3, 20, '20240207', 2),
       (4, 21, '20240212', 5),
       (5, 22, '20240212', 3),
       (5, 23, '20240211', 3),
       (5, 24, '20240210', 3),
       (7, 25, '20240212', 0)
```

I'm trying to use CTE, without cursor.

```
;WITH cte AS
( 
    SELECT 
        i.itemid, i.qtySum AS iQuantity,
        tr.trid, tr.qty AS trQuantity,
        SUM(tr.qty) OVER (PARTITION BY i.itemid ORDER BY tr.trdate desc ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS sum_amount
    FROM 
        #items i 
    INNER JOIN
        #transactions tr ON i.itemid = tr.itemid
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE sum_amount - iQuantity < trQuantity 

UNION

SELECT i.itemid, i.qtySum, NULL, NULL, NULL 
FROM #items i 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM cte c WHERE c.itemid = i.itemid)

DROP TABLE #items
DROP TABLE #transactions
```

and I have a problem with item #2.

Where, after I get exact amount, summary goes down, and selects additional rows.

Script selects id's 7,8,10,11. But I need only 7,8

[how to exclude with select these lines?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPlpP.png)

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: As an aside use `union all` not `union` because it performs better without having to de-dup the rows

Comment: Also change `SELECT TOP 1 1` to `SELECT 1`. There's no reason to introduce an arbitrary `TOP` there.

Comment: My bee ``WHERE sum_amount<= iQuantity  or (lag(sum_amount)< iQuantity  and sum_amount>= iQuantity)`` . Value sum_amount includes current row.

Comment: Please don't use images, use tabular text

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution, but fair warning, I don't think it's very elegant. Regardless, it *does* solve the problem. I'm also pretty sure with a little fiddling you could make this a single query not requiring temp tables. This is just how I thought about the problem.

The basic idea is I do a running sum over each `itemid`, and also keep track of what the running total was for the prior row. I then determine which row equaled-or-exceeded it's cutoff amount by checking if the previous running total was less than the cutoff, and the current running total equals-or-exceeds the cutoff. From there, it's a just a matter of getting the *first* `trid` value for each item where the sum was exceeded.

The problem with this approach is actually `itemid` 7, which never exceeds the amount and thus *has* no `trid` that meets the criteria above. So I sort of have to hack it back in at the end.

From there, you just select the original transactions less than or equal to the `CutoffTrid`

```
drop table if exists #work
-- Get the running total and the cutoff values
;with src as
(
    select
        t.itemid,
        t.trid,
        t.trdate,
        t.qty,
        Cutoff = i.qtySum,
        RunningTotal = sum(t.qty) over 
            (
                partition by t.itemid
                order by t.trdate desc
                rows between unbounded preceding and current row
            )
    from #transactions t
    inner join #Items i
        on t.ItemID = i.ItemId
)
-- Get the prior running total too.
select
    ItemId,
    trid,
    trdate,
    qty,
    Cutoff,
    RunningTotal,
    PriorRunningTotal = lag(RunningTotal, 1, null) over 
        (
            partition by ItemId 
            order by trdate desc
        )
into #Work
from src


/** Get Cutoff trids **/
drop table if exists #Cutoffs
-- First get all the lowest trid values where the running total equaled-or-exceeded the cutoff
select ItemId, CutoffTrid = min(trid)
into #Cutoffs
from #Work
where isnull(PriorRunningTotal, Cutoff - 1) < Cutoff
    and RunningTotal >= Cutoff
group by ItemId

-- Now we need to also insert trids for Items which never exceeded the cutoff, 
-- but need to be included also
insert into #Cutoffs
select
    s.ItemId,
    CutoffTrid = max(TRID)
from #Work s
left outer join #Cutoffs t
    on s.ItemId = t.ItemId
where s.RunningTotal < s.Cutoff
    and t.ItemId is null
group by s.ItemId

/** Final Result **/
select 
    w.ItemId,
    iQuantity = w.Cutoff,
    trid = w.trid,
    trQtantity = w.qty,
    sum_amount = RunningTotal
from #Work w
inner join #Cutoffs c
    on w.ItemId = c.itemId
        and w.trid <= c.CutoffTRID
```

**Results**

| ItemId | trid | Qty | RunningTotal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10.00 | 1 | 1.00 |
| 1 | 10.00 | 2 | 3.00 |
| 1 | 10.00 | 3 | 0.00 |
| 1 | 10.00 | 4 | 10.00 |
| 2 | 33.00 | 7 | 22.00 |
| 2 | 33.00 | 8 | 11.00 |
| 3 | 15.00 | 15 | 10.00 |
| 3 | 15.00 | 16 - | 2.00 |
| 3 | 15.00 | 17 - | 3.00 |
| 3 | 15.00 | 18 | 8.00 |
| 3 | 15.00 | 19 | 4.00 |
| 4 | 3.00 | 21 | 5.00 |
| 5 | 3.00 | 22 | 3.00 |
| 7 | 15.00 | 25 | 0.00 |

Full [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/nddAs54l)